# Is there a way to create a new team project using the TFS SDK?

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

I'm just getting started with the Team Foundation Server SDK and I'm wondering if there is a way to create a new Team Project using the SDK.

My goal in doing this is to create some automated tests to aid in system validation (being an FDA regulated company we are required to validate our in-house tools, to the extent this can be automated we can reduce costs). I would like to validate as much of the process end-to-end as possible (create a team project, check in some items to source control, create some work items, verify everything is stored/recalled correctly, etc). If there is a better approach or any existing work in this area I'm all ears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not using the tfs-sdk.  If you install [Team Explorer 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0ed12659-3d41-4420-bbb0-a46e51bfca86&displaylang=en), the [TFS 2008 power tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980963.aspx) and apply [VS 2008 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en) then you can use the tfpt createproject command to create a team project from a script (or execute the tfpt command as a process in your .NET application).  The command uses automation hooks added into Visual Studio in 2008 SP1 to automate the team project creation process.

When doing all this in an automated test environment, you'll probably have more luck doing this against a Virtual Machine (either VMWare or Microsoft Virtual PC / Hyper-V) and then you can automate rolling back the TFS instance to a known clean state each time you repeat your testing.